# Why fpdf library fail to work on production server?

Tags: php, fpdf

I am  export pdf from my php page  to  'pdf' in my localhost by using `fpdf library`.On my localhost the page is exported to pdf but when i host to the production server and work live ...
The datas are not  being exported to pdf
Why it is not exported on live
Actually i cant see any error also,,,,, but my page goes blank

Comment: Sounds like PHP error display has been disabled for starters, hence your blank page.  Turn on error display (php.ini, `error_reporting()` etc) and then show us the output. Alternatively, check your error logs if they're enabled.

Comment: are you using short tags on one server which might not be enabled on other server?

Comment: @ sAc :
short tags  in the sense i used <?=?> tag instead of <?php?>

Comment: @richsage: actually its being exported in my localhost so i think there is no problem

Comment: @sAc : It doesn't made difference same thing happens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also try to use

`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

in the beginning of your script

Comment: then look into server logs, look into empty page source in browser, ask production server provider if you are not the owner. do you have write permissions, what exporting exactly means?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following to view errors:

```
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

after reviewing the errors, i got my code to working by adding this on top of code:

```
include_once('fpdf182/fpdf.php');
ob_start();
```